# Как правильно обновить state компонента при получении новых props?

Tags: reactjs

Есть некий родительский компонент, который рендерит дочерний. Если родительский компонент изменяется, то он отправляет в уже отрендеренные дочерние компоненты новые пропсы. Моя проблема заключается в том, что при обновлении пропсов состояние компонента остаётся прежним и это вызывает нежелательное поведение интерфейса.

Например, в дочернем элементе есть кнопка "Показать больше", которая рендерит дочерний элемент. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы если пропсы изменились, то компонент должен обновить своё состояние:

```
this.setState({ isShowMoreActive: false })
```

Но как это правильно сделать? Метод жизненного цикла `componentWillRecieveProps()` устарел и скоро будет убран из Реакта, а документация [советует не использовать состояние вообще, а сделать компонент функциональным](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions).

Answer (score 2):

На смену `componentWillRecieveProps` пришел `getDerivedStateFromProps`, почитать [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

В вашем случае как мне кажется есть такие варианты:

- использование состояния (изменение внутреннего `state` компоненты)
- сделать компонент функциональным и использовать `hook` `useEffect` ([ссылка](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))
- использование переменной внутри классовой или функциональной компоненты (изменились `props` - поменяй значение переменной)

Comment: А если просто в `componentDidUpdate()` сравнить текущий `this.props` и `prevProps` и в случае изменения вызвать `this.setState()`?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin  можно и так, но это вызовет ререндер компоненты 2 раза (при изменении props и потом при изменении state)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin componentWillRecieveProps или getDerivedStateFromProps как раз избавит вас от повторного рендера